# Cannot find file path error for dir /b - Copying all file names script

Tags: powershell

I am trying to use a script that I've used before in Powershell, that is supposed to copy and paste all the file names inside a folder, into a text file.

I was able to use this script on a different computer last week, but can't do it now on my laptop.

Is there something I am not aware of?

The error it's giving is

`Cannot find path 'C:\b' because it does not exist.`

I tried removing the `/b` and I got a list of all the files but with other extra data like mode, last time write, length, name, and the extension of each file.

I really need the plain file name only. How can I do this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: "removing the `/b`" from what? How does your code look like?

Comment: Hi, I found a tutorial online a week ago and it worked. But now it doesn't anymore:

https://smallbusiness.chron.com/copy-file-names-windows-explorer-53696.html

Comment: I'm getting tired of this, but yeah.... "[Do not just post links] - but also copy the code into the question itself. Not everyone can access external sites, and the links may break over time." Found on [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the /b flag only works in cmd, not PowerShell

So you could try

```
cmd
dir /b
exit
```

Which will open CMD in your terminal and execute `dir /b` as a normal cmd command rather than PowerShell

**Alternatively, just use PowerShell's `Get-ChildItem` (or `gci` for short)**

To get just the plain file names using `Get-ChildItem`, you can do something like this:

```
# Assign the folder items to a variable $x
$x = gci
# Get only the names of those items
$x.name
```

See [SS64](https://ss64.com/) for details on CMD's [dir](https://ss64.com/nt/dir.html) and PowerShell's [Get-ChildItem](https://ss64.com/ps/get-childitem.html)

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing out that it should be on cmd instead of Power Shell! That solved it! Yay!!